# MachineKey not working

Tags: asp.net, configuration, web-farm

We have 3 balanced servers in our production Environment. We've been getting ViewState MAC validation error recently, but it only happens after 20 or 30 minutes. I am thinking maybe the balancer also has its own timeout, that it will redirect the same client to the same server within the same "session".

Anyhow, I updated machine config in all servers to have a fixed machineKey. But the error persists.

In the validationKey and DescriptionKey, I totally left out IsolateApps, so there's only the hash. Could that be the reason it's not working?

Comment: Try adding <pages enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never"> , or try this http://adam.kahtava.com/journal/2009/11/23/how-to-fix-the-validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: viewStateEncryptionMode's default value is auto, right? In our code we never manually set the code to encrypt...